# Stripe subscription (reactjs and nodejs) is succesful lbut no confirmation

Tags: node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments

I have a strange problem ....
I try to set up a subscription via Stripe in my ReactJs project. The payment goes through, I can see it in my Stripe dashboard, but my program doesn't continue to work ( I dont get a confirmation).

This is the front-end part:

```
const createSubscription = async (e) => {
try {
  e.preventDefault();
    const {error, paymentMethod} = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
    type: "card",
    card: elements.getElement(CardElement),
    billing_details: {
        name,
        email,           
    },
});

  const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:8800/create-sub", {
      paymentMethod: paymentMethod.id,
      name,
      email,
      priceId,
  }).then((res) => res.json)
  console.log('------------------');
  const confirmPayment = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(
    response.clientSecret
  );

  if (confirmPayment.error) {
    alert(confirmPayment.error.message);
  } else {
    alert("Success! Check your email for the invoice.");
  }
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

And this is the backend-part:

```
    app.post("/create-sub",  (req, res) => {
       createSubscription(req);    
});

async function createSubscription(reqq){
    let { paymentMethod, name, email, priceIdxx } = reqq.body
        const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
            name: name,
            email: email,
            payment_method: paymentMethod,
            invoice_settings: {
                default_payment_method: paymentMethod
            }
        });
        const priceId = 'price_1LmWAuEmOCxfDzgdORMhUQZD';
        const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.create({
            customer: customer.id,
            items: [{price: priceId}],
            payment_settings: {
                payment_method_options:                {
                    card: {
                        request_three_d_secure: 'automatic',
                    },
                },
                
            },
            expand: ['latest_invoice.payment_intent']

        });
        return {        

            clientSecret: subscription.latest_invoice.payment_intent.client_secret,
            subscriptionId: subscription.id,
            };
        
};
```

ClientSecret and SubscriptionId are being generated ( I can console log it).

As said, the transaction succeed (in Stripe dashboard) but I dont get a confirmation, it's like it is stuck somewhere. Weird thing too is that when I inspect the network (in Chrome), I see an instance of create-sub in 'pending' state. But no errors at backend side.
[create-sub 'pending'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnSGY.jpg)

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: It looks like your XHR request from frontend to backend never completes. Have you ever reached to the line of `res.json`? How about trying [Stripe official example][1]?

  [1]: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/card-element?lang=node

Comment: I’ve tried making a payment page for a shopping card and that works fine.
But this one is for a subscription based service which is a different flow. And really cant get it to work properly.